# No reducer provided for key reducer (reducer underfine)

Tags: react-native, redux-toolkit

I got an error when user authReduce. When log this reducer and it show "underfine"
I'm using:

- Redux persist store auth state
- Redux toolkit

Sometime  I try hot reload it work. So I don't understand why?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure for the import statement? from `@features/auth/authSlice`

Comment: yes, I use babel-plugin-module-resolver and decorator to write alias import

Comment: I think the reason is I export too much function inside the authSlice file. This file include authSlice, authAction, authReducer and many functions action of Midderware(thunk). So I try write a file for Reducer It worked

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did to resolve the problem I got stuck in the same situation with redux-toolkig and redux-persist

Comment: Hi @AleksandrFomin I answer this question below. Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears when I store reducer and actions in the same file (In one file have too many exports) so I resolved this problem by the way split reducer(authReducer.js) and actions(authSlice.js) are two files like this:

[image]

// authReducer.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    isLoading: true,
    userToken: null,
    isUserGuest: true,
    isJailBroken: false,
    isSubscription: true,
    isShowCheckPassCode: false,
    passCodeMessage: 'Đây là phiên bản nội bộ, Vui lòng nhập pass để sử dụng.',
    passCode: '',
    isShowPopupPassword: false,
    userEmail:'',
    typeLogin:'',
    isShowLoginGGFB:true
  },
  reducers: {
    signIn: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        const { token } = action.payload;
        state.userToken = token
        state.isLoading = false
      },
      prepare(token, userInfo) {
        return { payload: { token, userInfo } }
      }
    },
    skipAuth(state, action) {
      state.isUserGuest = true;
      state.userToken = null;
    },
    signout(state, action) {
      state.userToken = null
      state.isUserGuest = false;
    },
    setIsJailBroken(state, action) {
      state.isJailBroken = true
    },
    setSubscriptionNoti(state, action) {
      state.isSubscription = action.payload
    },
    setIsShowCheckPassCode(state, action) {
      state.isShowCheckPassCode = action.payload
    },
    setDataPasscode(state, action) {
      state.isShowCheckPassCode = action.payload.isShowCheckPassCode
      state.passCodeMessage = action.payload.passCodeMessage
      state.passCode = action.payload.passCode
    },
    setShowLoginGGFB(state, action){
      state.isShowLoginGGFB = action.payload
    },
    setActivePopupPassword(state, action) {
      state.isShowPopupPassword = action.payload
    },
    setUserEmail(state,action){
      state.userEmail = action.payload
    },
    setTypeLogin(state,action){
      state.typeLogin = action.payload
    }
  }
})

export const authReducer = authSlice.reducer
```

// authSlice.js

```
export const {
  signIn,
  signout,
  restore,
  skipAuth,
  setIsJailBroken,
  setSubscriptionNoti,
  setIsShowCheckPassCode,
  setDataPasscode,
  setActivePopupPassword,
  setUserEmail,
  setTypeLogin,
  setShowLoginGGFB,
} = authSlice.actions;

export const callActionSignOut = (isForce = true) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    if (isForce) {
      await signOut();
    }
    dispatch(signout());
    dispatch(
      setFavorite({
        dataFavorite: [],
        objectDataFavorite: {},
      }),
    );
    dispatch(fetchCartSuccess(null));
    dispatch(resetUserInternal());
    dispatch(clearUser());
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('callActionSignOut -> error', error);
  }
};
```